# Does Google uses AppEngine for its own products?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been wondering: does Google uses AppEngine for its own products?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Google's app engine is a consumer-facing front-end for the same server resources that google uses internally.

None of the major world-facing google products DIRECTLY use app engine through the API, but many internal tools built by googlers for googlers do use it, including all the limitations that are placed on the public.

Comment: Good info. Any sources / links to go with it?

Answer (score 5):

[​Run corporate applications on Google App Engine? Yes [they] do.](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/run-corp-apps-on-app-engine.html)